# Creating a new intent inside a for loop good or bad?

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I am currently stuck with the question, if creating a new intent inside a for loop is good or bad. I have the following situation:

**1.**

```
public static void reactivateReminders(Schedule schedule) {
    ArrayList<Lecture> allLectures = schedule.getAllLectures();

    for(Lecture lecture : allLectures) {
        ...
        // Set up various things for the reminder
        ...
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ReminderReceiver.class);
        String at = getResources().getString(R.string.at);
        String with = getResources().getString(R.string.with);
        String beginH = ScheduleHelper.formatNumber(changedBeginH);
        String beginM = ScheduleHelper.formatNumber(changedBeginM);
        String room = lecture.getRoom();
        intent.putExtra("contentText", at + " " + beginH + ":" + beginM + " in " + room + " " + with + " " + lecture.getLecturer());

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), lecture.getAlarmId(), intent, 0);//PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

        if(lecture.getBeginH() != beginH || lecture.getBeginM() != beginM)
            alarm.cancel(pendingIntent);

        alarm.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, calendar.getTimeInMillis() + offset, 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7, pendingIntent);
    }
}
```

**2.**

```
public static void reactivateReminders(Schedule schedule) {
    ArrayList<Lecture> allLectures = schedule.getAllLectures();
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ReminderReceiver.class);

    for(Lecture lecture : allLectures) {
        ...
        // Set up various things for the reminder
        ...
        String at = getResources().getString(R.string.at);
        String with = getResources().getString(R.string.with);
        String beginH = ScheduleHelper.formatNumber(changedBeginH);
        String beginM = ScheduleHelper.formatNumber(changedBeginM);
        String room = lecture.getRoom();
        intent.putExtra("contentText", at + " " + beginH + ":" + beginM + " in " + room + " " + with + " " + lecture.getLecturer());

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), lecture.getAlarmId(), intent, 0);//PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

        if(lecture.getBeginH() != beginH || lecture.getBeginM() != beginM)
            alarm.cancel(pendingIntent);

        alarm.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, calendar.getTimeInMillis() + offset, 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7, pendingIntent);
    }
}
```

Which option is the better one? I'm not too familiar with Java so I don't know how Java handles either one. Maybe is doesn't make a difference at all but since I'm programming in C++ normally, creating new objects inside a loop worries me.

Thanks for any help in advance.

**Edit: Conclusion**:
As mentioned by Alex Shutov, it better to not set all reminders at once. The user probably only needs the next one that is coming up.

To achieve this, you should set the earliest reminder somewhere in the app and store the other reminders (or rather the data you use for it) sorted in some place outside the app (XML, SQL, ...) so that your service can, after the earliest reminder set off, read the file to load the next one.

By doing this, you don't burden the system with reminders that the user doesn't even need yet. I will try to implement this idea sometime but for now I will use my approach.

**Regarding my code:**
A better approach for my posted code is to create the new intent once outside the loop. Since the extra I put in it has the same key, it will overwrite every time and you don't have to create a new intent. Other variables like my "at" and "with", which are constant, can be placed outside of the loop too. The variables "beginH, beginM, room" can be removed and you can just call the functions directly in the putExtra parameter. You can also place the PendingIntent and the AlarmManager line outside the loop.

I would post the code but I think my post will be too big then.
Thanks for the fast help :)

Comment: is it necessary to loop through? because you are using only last element why don't you directly use it?

Comment: it is not good way to create variables inside for loop in any way. do it only if you need it actually

Comment: Its a really bad idea !

Comment: @Prashant Thanks for the info with the variables. Is it better to create all variables that I use outside the loop and then just set them inside the loop? I also don't understand your first comment. Could you please explain it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a bad idea, because you overload system with unneccessary tasks, you should instead schedule nearest event, in IntentService schedule next event

Comment: Thought as much.. I just checked the RAM usage of my app and it uses around 50 MB although I only had one schedule with a couple of lectures and reminders. Do you have a small example for your suggestion? I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: I mean, you BroadcastReceiver starts IntentService, which in turn, load from database current notification, handles it, then it computes next notification (IntentService run on background thread) and schedules next update. After that it stops itself authomatically. See examples from this guide http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidServices/article.html

Comment: Sorry but I still don't get what you mean.. Do you suggest that I should put the code where I set up the alarm into the service?

Comment: No, you should create some class, which can save and remove tasks and take nearest task and schedule it. You save all tasks, then schedule first task somewhere in app. Service will be launched at a time of first event. In it  so some work, take and schedule next task

Comment: I think I understand now. You suggest to set the first reminder somewhere in my app and when the reminder gets off, I set the next reminder inside the service instead of setting all at once in my app, right?. I'd have to store all lectures sorted somewhere in a helper class. But can I just access the static helper class from the service even if my app is closed?